# Ubuntu fresh install help

Tags: boot, system-installation

I want to know how to freshly install ubuntu. I currently made a bootable disk, but when I plugged it in and turn my pc on, it doesn't do anything. I was expecting that the window will come up and show me the "on-screen" instructions. I don't think this is problem. I want to know how... Sorry for this "noobish" question.

Comment: How did you make your usb/dvd bootable?
And what is the filesystem you did use? Answer these and I may be able to have the answer to your question.

Comment: did you choose your bootaboe disk on start up?